# ffmpeg, histeq, palettegen and paletteuse behaviour

Tags: ffmpeg

Using ffmpeg, passing a video though `histeq` then `palettegen` and `paletteuse` generates strange output.

**Example 1**

```
wget https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_2MB.mp4
 
ffmpeg -ss  00:00:09.126 -t 0:0:01.0 -i Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_2MB.mp4  -filter_complex "histeq=0.01,split[a][b];[a] palettegen [p];[b][p] paletteuse" -y example.gif
```

[image: example 1]

**Example 2**

Adding another filter to the chain fixes it.

```
ffmpeg -ss  00:00:09.126 -t 0:0:01.0 -i Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_2MB.mp4  -filter_complex "histeq=0.01,eq,split[a][b];[a] palettegen [p];[b][p] paletteuse" -y example.gif
```

[image: example2]

Note the additional `eq` filter after `histeq` in the second example but why should it make a difference? Shouldn't the first example give the same result?

**UPDATE**

The only difference between the two examples is the filter chain. So specifically my question is why do the following two filter chains produce different results?

```
# from example 1:
histeq=0.01,split[a][b];[a] palettegen [p];[b][p] paletteuse

# from example 2:
histeq=0.01,eq,split[a][b];[a] palettegen [p];[b][p] paletteuse
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the input format to `histeq` is `bgra` applying histogram equalization to the alpha (transparency) channel gives strange results.

For fixing the issue we have to explicitly select `rgb24` (or `bgr24`) format before applying `histeq` filter:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:09.126 -t 0:0:01.0 -i Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_2MB.mp4 -filter_complex "format=rgb24,histeq=0.01,split[a][b];[a]palettegen[p];[b][p]paletteuse" -y example.gif
```

(For testing we may select `format=bgra` instead of `format=rgb24`, and get the poor output).

---

`histeq` filter include automatic format conversion at the input, but due to a bug (I assume) the above filter chain causes it to pick the wrong format.

Using `-loglevel debug`, we can see more details:
`ffmpeg -i Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_2MB.mp4 -filter_complex "histeq=0.01,split[a][b];[a]palettegen[p];[b][p]paletteuse" -y example.gif`

Here we can see that filter `'auto_scale'` is inserted before `histeq` filter, and applied conversion from `yuv420p` to `bgra`:

> [auto_scale_0 @ 00000255ecbe6440] w:iw h:ih flags:'' interl:0
> [Parsed_histeq_0 @ 00000255eae16f00] auto-inserting filter 'auto_scale_0' between the filter 'graph 0 input from stream 0:0' and the filter 'Parsed_histeq_0'
> [AVFilterGraph @ 00000255ec41d080] query_formats: 7 queried, 7 merged, 1 already done, 0 delayed
> [auto_scale_0 @ 00000255ecbe6440] w:1920 h:1080 fmt:yuv420p sar:1/1 -> w:1920 h:1080 fmt:bgra sar:1/1 flags:0x0

When using MP4 as output (without paltetgen): `ffmpeg -loglevel debug -i Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_2MB.mp4 -filter_complex "histeq=0.01" -y example.mp4`, `rgb24` format is picked (and the result look fine):

> [auto_scale_0 @ 000001d884baec80] picking rgb24 out of 6 ref:yuv420p alpha:0
> [auto_scale_1 @ 000001d884baef80] picking yuv444p out of 13 ref:rgb24 alpha:0
> [auto_scale_0 @ 000001d884baec80] w:1920 h:1080 fmt:yuv420p sar:1/1 -> w:1920 h:1080 fmt:rgb24 sar:1/1 flags:0x0
> [auto_scale_1 @ 000001d884baef80] w:1920 h:1080 fmt:rgb24 sar:1/1 -> w:1920 h:1080 fmt:yuv444p sar:1/1 flags:0x0

When `eq` filter is used before `histeq`, the input to `eq` is `bgra`.
It's difficult to answer why `eq` fixes the problem (I assume that the output of `eq` in not `bgra`).

---

Note:
Applying histogram equalization on RGB is fine but not ideal (assume histogram equalization is applied on red, green and blue separately).
When applying histogram equalization on colored image, it is recommended to convert the image to [LAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space) color space, applying histogram equalization only on the luminance, and converting back to RGB.
We can't apply the suggested procedure because FFmpeg doesn't support LAB color space.

Comment: fantastic answer. I'll file bug report too.